# Feet and Inches in same input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an input field with feet and inches in one box.

When user types a number, I want the feet symbol `'` to appear after it.

**Example:**

```
------------------------
| 5'                   |
------------------------
```

Then when the user presses spacebar and types the second number, I want the inches symbol `"` to appear after it.

**Example:**

```
------------------------
| 5' 7"                |
------------------------
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Well, you have more than 1k rep, so you should know by now that you have to try it yourself first, and only ask a question if you have a problem with your own actual code.  Just asking how to do something like this is very lazy.

Comment: @JK. I tried to do it but I couldnt get it to work.

Comment: should also know to post html .... not useless text representation. Show what you tried...people aren't here to do your work for you but had you posted a code attempt you would likely have a solution by now instead of stacking up close votes

Comment: How will it work if someone wants to enter `10'`? Why not just use only inches, or have 2 inputs, or use `cm` like the rest of the world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myKeyPress(e){
                var input = document.getElementById('txt');
                var enteredChar = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
                if (isNaN(parseInt(enteredChar) || enteredChar != ' '))
                    return false;
                if(input.value.length == 0) {
                    input.value += enteredChar + "'";
                    return false;
                }
                if(input.value.length == 3) {
                    input.value += enteredChar + '"';
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="txt" type="text" onkeypress="return myKeyPress(event)"/>
    </body>
</html>
```